# passing an object to a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

if have a jQuery code

```js
var info = $("#info");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $("p").eq(i).on("click", function(event) {
    var reply = [
      " message=message for first p",
      "index = " + $(this).index(),


    ];
    info.append(reply.join(", ") + "<br>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> 0 </p>
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
<div id="info"></div>
```

here inside the reply array I need to add custom messages for each `p` based on the values given as arguments in the function dynamically.How can i achieve it in jquery?I know little that `data` attribute can be used but not clear about it.

**UPDATE**:
I need an object to store the values inside `on()` method.

Comment: _"based on the values given as arguments in the function"_ Which function, the `event` handler? What do you mean by "dynamically"? Note `for` loop and `.eq()` are not necessary.

Comment: @guest271314 i hv updated my question hope it sounds more clear now

Comment: _"I need an object to store the values inside on() method."_ Are you trying store current `reply` variable in an object  at each `click` event?

Comment: Values like an array of index for each p

Comment: Yes, are you trying to push each `reply` variable created within `click` handler to an array accessible within and without `click` handler? Are you only trying to push the index of current `p` element to an array?

Comment: Yes thats exactly I want

Comment: In a separate array than `reply` array?

Comment: Yes an array independent of reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, `for` loop, `.eq()` and creating an array to call `.join(", ")` on are not necessary.

`$("p")` selects all `<p>` elements in `document` without a filter being applied to selector.

You can concatenate string fragments without creating an array and `.join()`.

Call `this.tagName`:`"P"` as parameter to `.index()`, push result to an array defined outside of `click` handler.

```js
var info = $("#info");
var arr = [];
var p = $("p").on("click", function(event) {
    var index = $(this).index(this.tagName);
    var reply = " message=message for first p"
                + ", index = " 
                + index
    arr.push(index);
    info.append(reply + "<br>");
    console.log(arr);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> 0 </p>
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `data` attribute the just store your message on a `data` attribute (like `data-message`) and the get it using `jQueryElement.attr('data-message')` or `jQueryElemenet.data('message')` like this:

```js
var info = $("#info");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $("p").eq(i).on("click", function(event) {
    var message = $(this).data("message"); // get the data-message of this p
    info.append(message + "<br>");         // use it ...
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-message="hey this is the first"> 0 </p>
<p data-message="and this is 2"> 1 </p>
<p data-message="this will be the THIRD"> 2 </p>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: @charlietfl OP asked if he can use different messages for different p elements! Event listening is his choice!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i appreciate your answer but thats not exactly what i want